# Adding random values to python list elements

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list :

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want to add a different random number to each element in the list using np.random.randn()
I start by creating another list containing the rando values by using:

```
noise = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    b = (random_noise * np.random.randn())
    noise.append(b)
```

And the add the two lists

```
a + b
```

My question is, is there a simplified method in which i can add the noise directly to a elements without the need to creating the loop, in seek of saving time in the large problems.

Comment: If you want to switch to numpy, which you probably want to do, then you can generate an array of randoms and add that to the original data.  In straight Python, it requires a loop.

Comment: It is syntactic sugar, but you could use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn `a` into a numpy array, you can do

```py
>>> a = np.array(a)
>>> a2 = a + np.random.randn(a.size)
>>> a2
array([-0.1199694 ,  1.64558727,  3.10977101,  5.66627737,  4.95481395,
        7.63834891,  7.48148948,  8.55867759,  8.02858298,  9.77297563])
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the noise as np array and add it to a

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
noise = np.random.randn(len(a))
print(a+noise)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
a = [x + np.random.randn() for x in range(1, 10)]
print(a)
```

output:

`[0.31328085156307206, 0.8473128208005949, 4.574220370196114, 3.7338991251803195, 4.9131070198281686, 5.4760389038550565, 7.328982658187497, 6.716468468134682, 9.491303138695487]`